# Short form for Java if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, ternary-operator

I know there is a way for writing a Java `if` statement in short form.

```
if (city.getName() != null) {
    name = city.getName();
} else {
    name="N/A";
}
```

Does anyone know how to write the short form for the above 5 lines into one line?

Comment: google [ternary operator in java](https://www.google.com/search?q=ternary+operator+java) :)

Comment: I assume you got your `if` logic the wrong way round.

Comment: `if (city.getName()!=null){name = city.getName();}else{name="N/A"}`

Comment: @SteveKuo There are three spaces you can remove. ;)

Comment: `if (city.getName()!= null) name = city.getName(); else name="N/A";`

Answer (score 562, accepted):

Use the ternary operator:

```
name = ((city.getName() == null) ? "N/A" : city.getName());
```

I think you have the conditions backwards - if it's null, you want the value to be "N/A".

What if city is null?  Your code *hits the bed in that case.  I'd add another check:

```
name = ((city == null) || (city.getName() == null) ? "N/A" : city.getName());
```

Comment: +1, though you have redundant parentheses. I would have written:

    `name = city.getName() == null ? "N/A" : city.getName();`

Comment: A matter of style and taste: I like to make the grouping of the boolean clause clear.

Comment: Whatever - I used DeMorgan's theorem and got what you needed.  No need to edit, as long as you express the logic correctly.

Comment: The logic is correct.  The only possible flaw with this answer is if city is mutable.

Comment: FYI the outer parenthesis are unnecessary. You can just do `name = city.getName()==null ? "N/A" : city.getName()`

Comment: Yeah, I know.  Like I said above, it's a matter of taste.  It doesn't enhance or diminish the correctness of the answer.

Comment: @duffmo I'm not worried about threads - it's not my code.  Only "1000 ways AAAAAAAAH" knows the details - like whether getName is a standard getter method that always returns the same value - in which case your code is perfect.

Comment: Won't `String cityName = city.getName();` throw a `NullPointerException` if `city == null`? I'd therefore say your middle solution is definitely the best (PS and I approve of the  'unnecessary' parentheses! People need to remember that 99% of coding is communicating with other people (and your future self), not the compiler - otherwise we'd use c!)

Comment: Is there a way to include "else if" in this statement?

Comment: No. Is it too much to ask that you refer to a language reference?

Answer (score 48):

To avoid calling `.getName()` twice I would use

```
name = city.getName();
if (name == null) name = "N/A";
```

Comment: In a multi user system with a mutable city, there could be an intervening `city.setName(null)`.  Your answer neatly handles that.

Answer (score 35):

The way to do it is with ternary operator:

```
name = city.getName() == null ? city.getName() : "N/A"
```

However, I believe you have a typo in your code above, and you mean to say:

```
if (city.getName() != null) ...
```

Answer (score 35):

> The ? : operator in Java

In Java you might write:

```
if (a > b) {
  max = a;
}
else {
  max = b;
}
```

Setting a single variable to one of two states based on a single condition is such a common use of if-else that a shortcut has been devised for it, the conditional operator, ?:. Using the conditional operator you can rewrite the above example in a single line like this:

```
max = (a > b) ? a : b;
```

(a > b) ? a : b; is an expression which returns one of two values, a or b. The condition, (a > b), is tested. If it is true the first value, a, is returned. If it is false, the second value, b, is returned. Whichever value is returned is dependent on the conditional test, a > b. The condition can be any expression which returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 33):

I'm always forgeting how to use the `?:` [ternary operator](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018). This supplemental answer is a quick reminder. It is shorthand for `if-then-else`.

```
myVariable = (testCondition) ? someValue : anotherValue;
```

where

- `()` holds the `if`
- `?` means `then`
- `:` means `else`

It is the same as

```
if (testCondition) {
    myVariable = someValue;
} else {
    myVariable = anotherValue;
}
```

Answer (score 27):

> **1.** You can remove **brackets** and **line breaks**.

```
if (city.getName() != null) name = city.getName(); else name = "N/A";
```

---

> **2.** You can use **?:** operators in java.

**Syntax:**

```
Variable = Condition ? BlockTrue : BlockElse;
```

So in your code you can do like this:

```
name = city.getName() == null ? "N/A" : city.getName();
```

---

> **3.** Assign condition result for **Boolean**

```
boolean hasName = city.getName() != null;
```

---

**EXTRA:** *for curious*

In some languages based in `JAVA` like `Groovy`, you can use this syntax:

```
name = city.getName() ?: "N/A";
```

The operator `?:` assign the value returned from the variable which we are asking for. In this case, the value of `city.getName()` if it's not `null`.

Answer (score 23):

in java 8:

```
name = Optional.ofNullable(city.getName()).orElse("N/A")
```

Answer (score 11):

```
name = (city.getName() != null) ? city.getName() : "N/A";
```

Answer (score 11):

You can write `if, else if, else` statements in short form. For example:

```
Boolean isCapital = city.isCapital(); //Object Boolean (not boolean)
String isCapitalName = isCapital == null ? "" : isCapital ? "Capital" : "City";
```

This is short form of:

```
Boolean isCapital = city.isCapital();
String isCapitalName;
if(isCapital == null) {
    isCapitalName = "";
} else if(isCapital) {
    isCapitalName = "Capital";
} else {
    isCapitalName = "City";
}
```

Comment: This was not asked so still -1.

Answer (score 7):

here is one line code

```
name = (city.getName() != null) ? city.getName() : "N/A";
```

here is example how it work, run below code in js file and understand the result. This `("Data" != null)` is condition as we do in normal `if()` and `"Data"` is statement when this condition became true. this `" : "` act as else and `"N/A"` is statement for else condition. Hope this help you to understand the logic.

```js
name = ("Data" != null) ? "Data" : "N/A";

console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could make it much easier this way :

```
name = city.getName() == null ? city.getName() : "N/A"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will throw a NullPointerException everytime. `city.getName()` and `"N/A"` should be inverted. Ternary operators work like : `boolean_expression ? execute_if_true : execute_if_false`
[https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator](documentation)

Answer (score 4):

Use org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils:

```
name = StringUtils.defaultString(city.getName(), "N/A");
```

Answer (score 4):

***Simple & clear:***

```
String manType = hasMoney() ? "rich" : "poor";
```

long version:

```
      String manType;
    if (hasMoney()) {
        manType = "rich";
    } else {
        manType = "poor";
    }
```

or how I'm using it to be clear for other code readers:

```
 String manType = "poor";
    if (hasMoney())
        manType = "rich";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
name = ( (city.getName() == null)? "N/A" : city.getName() );
```

firstly the condition `(city.getName() == null)` is checked. If yes, then `"N/A"` is assigned to name or simply `name="N/A"` or else the value from `city.getName()` is assigned to name, i.e. `name=city.getName()`.

Things to look out here:

1. condition is in the parenthesis followed by a question mark. That's why I write `(city.getName() == null)?`. Here the question mark is right after the condition. Easy to see/read/guess even!
2. value left of colon (`:`) and value right of colon 
   (a) value left of colon is assigned when condition is true, else the value right of colon is assigned to the variable.

here's a reference: http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8+ you have 2 solution.
With short if statement:

```
Objects.nonNull(city.getName())? city.getName(): "N/A";
```

Better solution in your case is use Optional:

```
Optional.ofNullable(city)
            .map(City::getName)
            .orElse("N/A");
```

Answer (score -3):

One line, avoiding second call to method (and creation of additional `Optional` instance):

```
if ( (name = city.getName()) == null ) name = "N/A";
```

<sub>partly based on source code of standard Java classes</sub>

Answer (score -5):

```
name = city.getName()!=null?city.getName():"N/A"
```

Comment: Instead of just posting some code you would help OP more by explaining the technique. How does it work, why does it work?

Comment: Putting spaces around your operators make it much easier to read & maintain.