# Compere if statement short form

Tags: java

ı want to use **short form** for if statement. How can ı write if statement at **one line**? and how can ı compare them ı know there is same question at here. but my statement do not have **else** so ı could not do it without else statement.

```
public int compareTo(Uyum u) {
            if (uyum < u.uyum)
                return -1;
            if (uyum > u.uyum)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898590/short-form-for-java-if-statement

Comment: Use the ternary operator.

Comment: `return uyum < u.uyum? -1 : uyum > u.uyum? 1 : 0;`

Comment: Just noticing it's not a full duplicate. You have three cases, the short version only works for two or more exactly only `if`-`else` and not even `if`-`else if`.

Comment: but it has else method ı dont have else method and ı cant convert

Comment: It's a trivial extension 'though.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Okay, that would work but I wouldn't recommend it to OP because it's very hard to read.

Comment: @stonedsquirrel That's just because you're not used to it. I use it all the time and it is very readable (especially when properly formatted in several lines). If you had experience with languages such as Clojure, which posses the `cond` construct, you'd find it very obvious, too.

Comment: How about ((Comparable) uyum).compareTo(u.uyum)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik if you say so. I guess I'll never get used to it. I even avoid the single ternary operator ;-)

Comment: @user2583040 That was an invalid edit.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot what can ı do for fixed question please tell ı have block due to this question

Comment: @user2583040 Ask a new question !

Comment: @TheNewIdiot relax dude ı only ask what can ı do with kindly. ı dont change my question ı changed grammer error

Comment: @TheNewIdiot ı asked short form my question and still ı ask short form.. ı dont understand you and ı dont like "!"character. please relax. ı am new at this website. so ı have block ı try yo change my mistake

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34467/discussion-between-user2583040-and-the-new-idiot)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short form for Java If statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898590/short-form-for-java-if-statement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator :

```
 return uyum < u.uyum ? -1 
      : uyum > u.uyum ? 1 
      : 0;
```

Comment: Sorry for messing with your code, but I just wanted to demonstrate that this idiom can be very readable and intuitive, no matter how many conditions there are.

Comment: @markoTopolnik Thanks for making the code readable , always open to suggestions from experienced people :)

Comment: Actually, the last :0 should have one more level of indentation, to be completely readable, no?

Comment: @mdm No, all the colons should be aligned. Think of if-else if-else if. The same thing happens there.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Ok, but that makes it quite less readable, IMO. In this case it's ok, because conceptually the three conditions are complementary and cover all the spectrum, but what if that was not the case? just being picky, I guess :)

Comment: @mdm So do you indent the final `else` in an `if-else if` cascade? That would be exceedingly strange and against the conventions, but it would be a direct analog to indenting the final line in the code above.

Comment: I see your point now. Admittedly, I do not indent in case of else-if's. I'll think about it next time I use the ternary operator :)

Answer (score 2):

You perhaps want:

```
return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: @Marko - maybe you don't need them, I do :)

Comment: Actually this idiom can be very readably written in several lines, to look just like Lisp's `cond` macro, or a map from condition to result.

Comment: BTW if you have more than just two conditions, the parens will only make it worse.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You're right, but in that case I'd code differently anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you may simply write this:

public int compareTo(Uyum u) {

```
return uyum - u.uyum;
```

}

Comment: That will not return the correct answer. The results should be one of either `-1`, `0` or `1`.

Comment: @snipes83 Actually, it will. Check the documentation on `Comparable`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik How do you know that OP is implementing `Comparable`? :) OP doesn't say.

Comment: @snipes83 Let's say it's a wild guess at my part :)

Comment: Also, there are limit cases even if he's implementing `Comparable` - what happens if one is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and the other `Integer.MIN_VALUE` ? Better to use `Integer.compare(int a, int b)` if running Java 1.7, or use the ternary operator otherwise.

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo A simple cast of either argument to `long` would fix it, too --- unless they are already `long`s :)

Comment: I thought this had a (small) [overhead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170872/does-java-casting-introduce-overhead-why) though, why do that when you have perfectly readable and correct alternatives?

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo Clearly, all this discussion is just chitchat, so why not throw in every possible alternative anybody can think of :)

Answer (score 0):

Inline if statement (question mark) are normally only desired if you have two states. Readability of your code is very important.
In your case you have 3 states (0, 1 and -1); I would not recommend using the inline if statement.

Example inline if statement:

```
String value = variable==null?"defaultvalue":variable;
```

This if statement notation is called [ternary operator](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `u.uyum` is an int, in which case, why is the following not satisfactory?

```
return Integer.compare(uyum, u.uyum)
```

If you really must use a ternary operator, you can do as everybody else is suggesting:

```
return uyum > u.uyum ? 1 : uyum == u.uyum ? 0 : -1
```

This tends to be frowned upon though, as it's not terribly legible.

Comment: How can you say it's an Int? It could be short, char, double, even bool. Hence `((Comparable) uyum)`, it will box to the correct type.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause compilation warnings (`unsafe call to compareTo(T) yadda yadda yadda`) though?

Comment: Do you mean casting to `Comparable<Object>`? That seemed somewhat fishy to me, so I gave it a go and it doesn't compile. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo I have withdrawn that comment. However, it must be possible to find a notation that covers all primitives!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik  Yes, but wasn't the whole (laudable) point of the initial comment to avoid assuming `uyum` was an `Integer`?

Comment: @Ingo I'm sure you're right, I was hoping you knew it and would teach it to me :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'm sure it is, but the whole point of this derailed comment thread was to pretend we didn't know the type of `uyum` and to find a way to perform the comparison nevertheless. If we know the type of `uyum`, there's no point to @Ingo and I's discussion, nor is there any fun to be had. We like fun. Don't you?

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo Ooops, missed that, you are absolutely right :)

Comment: So, in the spirit of fun check out this beauty: `public int compareTo(Uyum u) {
        return compare(uyum, u.uyum);
      }
      static <T extends Comparable<T>> int compare(T left, T right) {
        return left.compareTo(right);
      }
` You can make `Uyum#uyum` any numeric type you want.

Comment: You, sir, are a true artist.

Answer (score 0):

`return (uyum-u.uyum)==0?0:((uyum-u.uyum)<0?-1:1)`

Comment: What if uyum is **boolean**?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Is that true! Java won't compare boolean! Now I understand better why people hate Java.

Comment: @Ingo Among all the things why people hate Java I have never, ever heard of the "uncomparable boolean" complaint. I have also never had a use case where that would be useful.

Comment: You see one here: Abstracting over the (primitive) type that is in some class. Consider: I could more or less generically sort the following `class Person { int gender; String name, int age; }` Now someone comes on and points correctly out that `int gender;` should be better `boolean female;` And now, with that better design, the sortability is lost?