# Size screen issue

Tags: java, android, size, screen

for some reason, the application when reading the screen size getRealSize () began to give unreal sizes and 25 % less. 
I have a screen of 1920*1080, and gives 1440*810.
When I start a project, the screen size shows correctly. But after the build for publication, this problem begins.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); Point point = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(point);}
```

Comment: can you use this solution to see if it works or add your solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/8898617/8925577

Comment: Post your actual code, so we can be sure you aren't misusing something.  Also, make sure that your virtual density matches physical density (some phones are set up to say pixels are bigger than they are, thus reducing screen size in pixels).

Comment: I added the code, her is simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Dimension from Toolkit

*Code:*

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

System.out.println("Screen Width: " + screenSize.getWidth());

System.out.println("Screen Height: " + screenSize.getHeight());
```

Comment: when I install the game with android studio, everything is fine, and when I install play market, this problem occurs, and then with android studio I install this problem becomes permanent